# R Shiny - Highlight datapoints on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, interactive

I'm wanting to highlight adjacent datapoints on mouse hover, with a textbox (on-graph) displaying the x and y variables, WITHOUT using plotly (I don't like the additonal features plotly provides, or its banners above - great package, just not what I'm looking for in this application).

Essentially recreating the "Goods and Services Trade" and "Trade balance" graphs on the main page of the main page here: https://gallery.shinyapps.io/nz-trade-dash/?_ga=2.125477258.1669624743.1664839955-1927531303.1660016860

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi, please make a [*minimal* and *reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). For R Shiny, that means making the `ui` and `server` parts as small as possible so that you can clearly show the problem. You may also be interested in the [`ggiraph` package](https://davidgohel.github.io/ggiraph/)

Comment: Hi @bretauv, the issue is that I'm searching for a feature, not debugging. A reproducible example would involve the ```server``` and ```ui``` simply inserting a ggplot, and the ggplot would just be a ```ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()```. I wish to recreate the example, but in the meantime shall checkout the ```ggiraph``` package. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be using the Highcharts package, by Joshua Kunst.

It, 'Is a R wrapper for Highcharts javascript library and its modules. Highcharts is very flexible and customizable javascript charting library and it has a great and powerful API':
[https://jkunst.com/highcharter/#:~:text=Highcharter%20is%20a%20R%20wrapper,x)%20you%20can%20chart%20data](https://jkunst.com/highcharter/#:%7E:text=Highcharter%20is%20a%20R%20wrapper,x)%20you%20can%20chart%20data)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33703160)